# I am facing issue with the meilisearch autocomplete features

Tags: meilisearch

I have used docsSearchBar for the autocomplete but facing this issues "Uncaught (in promise) Error: [groupBy]: Object has no key lvl0". So, anyone please help me out.

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide the steps to reproduce the issue?